# How to update only one key value of nested json in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework. I have a Nested Json like below -

```
 "db_result": {
    "db_result_emp": [
      {
        "emp_id": 1110,
        "name": "abc",
        "address": 2,
        "street1": 1,
        "street2": 0,
      },
      {
        "emp_id": 1111,
        "name": "xyz",
        "address": 2,
        "street1": 1,
        "street2": 0,
      }
    ]
```

i want to update name of emp id 1110 to ```"name":"zzz" i tried below keywords

`${updated_json_value}=  Update Value To Json  ${json_sub_header_key_content}  $..name  ${emp_name}`

But above keyword updates for both the emp_id's i.e 1110, 1111
How can i update the key value for only emp_id 1110?

Answer (score 0):

First of all a little correction to your posted JSON. You have trailing commas in your objects, which isn't allowed, so you need to remove those:

```
{
    "db_result": {
        "db_result_emp": [
            {
                "emp_id": 1110,
                "name": "abc",
                "address": 2,
                "street1": 1,
                "street2": 0
            },
            {
                "emp_id": 1111,
                "name": "xyz",
                "address": 2,
                "street1": 1,
                "street2": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

You could use this JSONPath

```
$..[?(@.emp_id==1110)].name
```

Comment: @porglezomp i am getting an error when i use above jsonpath ```Parse error at 1:4 near token ? (?)```